# The difference between RGB and RGBA rulle in CSS(both accept Alpha value)?

Tags: html, css

Why is there two rules in CSS like RGB and RGBA since both rules accept alpha channel 
example:

```
rgb(0,0,0,0.5);
```

is the same as

```
rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
```

whats the difference when they both accept Alpha value?

Comment: well browser knows it's rgba and render correctly if you inspect you can see it's rgba in color picker

Answer (score 3):

If you write `rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` some browsers use fourth number to set as opacity, but some don't use. If you want to have a color with opacity, and view truly on all browsers, you need to use `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)`

Answer (score 2):

`rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` should never be used, I'm not exactly sure where it was introduces and why. But in [CSS Color Module Level 4 (Editor’s Draft, 23 January 2019)](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#rgb-functions) they explicitly say:

> For legacy reasons, rgb() also supports an alternate syntax that separates all of its arguments with commas:
>
> ```
>   rgb() = rgb( <percentage>#{3} , <alpha-value>? ) |
>           rgb( <number>#{3} , <alpha-value>? )
> ```

So maybe it appeared in a draft and was removed again, but in between it probably was already implemented by the browser vendors.

With css 2.1 `rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` is not valid. And is also rejected by the official [css-validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

With css 3  `rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` is still not valid based on the specification:

[css-color-3#rgb-color](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-color-3/#rgb-color)

> The format of an RGB value in the functional notation is ‘rgb(’ followed by a comma-separated list of three numerical values (either three integer values or three percentage values) followed by ‘)’. The integer value 255 corresponds to 100%, and to F or FF in the hexadecimal notation: rgb(255,255,255) = rgb(100%,100%,100%) = #FFF. White space characters are allowed around the numerical values.

The [css-validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/) seems to accept `rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)` and validates it as  `rgb(0 0 0 / 0.5)` if css 3 is selected, but that's more because of that legacy support.

With [CSS Color Module Level 4 (Editor’s Draft, 23 January 2019)](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-color/#rgb-functions) the format `rgb(0 0 0 / 0.5)` is introduced:

> ```
>  rgb() = rgb( <percentage>{3} [ / <alpha-value> ]? ) |
>          rgb( <number>{3} [ / <alpha-value> ]? )
> ```
>
> For legacy reasons, rgb() also supports an alternate syntax that separates all of its arguments with commas:
>
> ```
>   rgb() = rgb( <percentage>#{3} , <alpha-value>? ) |
>           rgb( <number>#{3} , <alpha-value>? )
> ```
>
> Also for legacy reasons, an rgba() function also exists, with an identical grammar and behavior to rgb().

So according to the specs use `rgb` for colors without alpha, and `rgba` for colors with alpha until css3.

And after that only use the new syntax, but never `rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)`.

So it seems that idea is to have uniform syntax only using `rgb` and to get rid of the `rgba` in future.